# Import NavigationDrawerSample Android L into Android Studio

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop

I was trying to import the NavigationDrawerSample Android L sample app,  into my android studio (0.8.9) but during the gradle build it throws an error and I cant compile the app. did anyone have luck importing this sample app?

Executing tasks: [:NavigationDrawerSample:generateDebugSources, :NavigationDrawerSample:generateDebugTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:NavigationDrawerSample:preBuild
:NavigationDrawerSample:preDebugBuild
:NavigationDrawerSample:checkDebugManifest
:NavigationDrawerSample:preReleaseBuild
:NavigationDrawerSample:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72000Library UP-TO-DATE
:NavigationDrawerSample:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72100Rc1Library UP-TO-DATE
:NavigationDrawerSample:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132000Library UP-TO-DATE
:NavigationDrawerSample:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Rc1Library UP-TO-DATE
:NavigationDrawerSample:prepareDebugDependencies
:NavigationDrawerSample:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:NavigationDrawerSample:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:NavigationDrawerSample:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:NavigationDrawerSample:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:NavigationDrawerSample:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:NavigationDrawerSample:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:NavigationDrawerSample:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:NavigationDrawerSample:mergeDebugResources
C:\temp\dev\AndroidL-Drawer\android-NavigationDrawer-master\android-NavigationDrawer-master\NavigationDrawerSample\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\20.0.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi\abc_textfield_search_right_selected_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file

Error: Failed to run command:
    C:\software\android-develop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514\sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe s -i C:\temp\dev\AndroidL-Drawer\android-NavigationDrawer-master\android-NavigationDrawer-master\NavigationDrawerSample\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\20.0.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi\abc_textfield_search_right_selected_holo_light.9.png -o C:\temp\dev\AndroidL-Drawer\android-NavigationDrawer-master\android-NavigationDrawer-master\NavigationDrawerSample\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_right_selected_holo_light.9.png
Error Code:
    42
Output:
    C:\temp\dev\AndroidL-Drawer\android-NavigationDrawer-master\android-NavigationDrawer-master\NavigationDrawerSample\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\20.0.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi\abc_textfield_search_right_selected_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file

:NavigationDrawerSample:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':NavigationDrawerSample:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Error: Failed to run command:
  >   C:\software\android-develop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130514\sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe s -i C:\temp\dev\AndroidL-Drawer\android-NavigationDrawer-master\android-NavigationDrawer-master\NavigationDrawerSample\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\20.0.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi\abc_textfield_search_right_selected_holo_light.9.png -o C:\temp\dev\AndroidL-Drawer\android-NavigationDrawer-master\android-NavigationDrawer-master\NavigationDrawerSample\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_right_selected_holo_light.9.png
  >   Error Code:
  >   42
  >   Output:
  >   C:\temp\dev\AndroidL-Drawer\android-NavigationDrawer-master\android-NavigationDrawer-master\NavigationDrawerSample\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\20.0.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi\abc_textfield_search_right_selected_holo_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be bug in aapt. I've managed to launch the app commenting line in build.gradle (support for old devices):

```
//    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+
```

and running app in AVD with Android L Preview.

Comment: Yes after commenting that line now compiles. Is this library for compatibility with the older api version?

Comment: Yep, please see: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html